# Asterisk real time configuration fail. asterisk trying to load my deleted sip user

Tags: asterisk

i was configuring asterisk Real time. i have done all configutaion according to the documentation but i am constantly having this error on asterisk.

“[Mar 6 23:37:17] NOTICE[4639]: chan_sip.c:28647 handle_request_register: Registration from ‘sip:1003@192.168.179.151;transport=UDP’ failed for ‘192.168.179.1:36551’ - Wrong password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That just mean no record or password not match.

For EXACTLY info you have enable debug mode.